# The TreeView hierarchy is generated wrongly

Tags: c#, treeview

I try to populate a TreeView at runtime hierarchically but something wrong is happening in my code.

Normally I should have many projects as the root nodes, followed by sub projects as sub nodes and so on.

Let's say projects 1, 9, 10, 62, and 65 are the roots or projects.

- Project #1 contains sub projects 17, 24, 33, 34, 35, 61, 98, ...
- Project #9 contains no sub projects.
- Project #10 contains sub projects 2 and 104.
- Project #62 contains sub projects 63, 64, 108, 109.
- Project #65 again has other sub projects.

[image]

**Problem:** The code keeps adding root nodes to each other. So it considers the next root node as the child of the previous one.

**Result:** The code should create separated root nodes with sub projects (sub projects can also contain subs).

**Code:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbConnector db = new DbConnector();
    string str = "";
    List<string> lst = db.ReadProjectsTable();
    lst.OrderBy(x => x.Count(y => y == '|'));

    List<string> newLst = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        string output = "";
        foreach (var item2 in item.Split('|', '|'))
        {
            output += item2 + '-';
        }
        output = output.Substring(output.IndexOf('-')+1, output.LastIndexOf('-')-2);
        newLst.Add(output);
        str += output + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    textBox2.Text = str;

    tvProjects.PathSeparator = @"-";

    PopulateTreeView(tvProjects, newLst, '-');
}

private static void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
{
    TreeNode lastNode = null;
    string subPathAgg;
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        subPathAgg = string.Empty;
        foreach (string subPath in path.Split(pathSeparator))
        {
            subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator;
            TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
            if (nodes.Length == 0)
                if (lastNode == null)
                    lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                else
                    lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
            else
                lastNode = nodes[0];
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
Sample data of `List<string> lst`

> |1|
>   |9| |10| |62| |65| |67| |78| |83| |86| |105| |116| |125| |10|2| |67|4|
>   |1|17| |1|24| |1|33| |1|34| |1|35| |1|61| |62|63| |62|64| |67|68|
>   |65|69| |65|70| |65|71| |65|72| |65|75|

Comment: Please provide the sample data - `List<string> lst = new List<strng> {... };`

Comment: Whitespace means a new item in the list

Comment: Your sample data cannot be parsed to give the results you want.  Input data should have a parent and child/children.  "1" has no parent.  The children of "1" are : "9", "17", "33", "110", "111", "128".  "9" is the parent of "10".  "10" is parent of "62".  "62" is parent of "65".  "65" is parent of "63", "64", "108", "109".

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the `lastNode` variable to `null` before entering the inner loop. And to avoid confusion and similar errors, better declare and initialize variables at the place where they are needed:

```
private static void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
{
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        string subPathAgg = string.Empty;
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        foreach (string subPath in path.Split(pathSeparator))
        {
            subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator;
            TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
            if (nodes.Length == 0)
                if (lastNode == null)
                    lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                else
                    lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
            else
                lastNode = nodes[0];
        }
    }
}
```